# Creating instances of a class that is derived in a different assembly

Tags: .net, class, assemblies, instance, derived

I had a difficult time coming up with a title for this issue.  Here is my best stab at describing the issue.

I have used generic class names here, but the point is the same.

In a DLL named Common.dll I have a class named FormControl.  It displays a button bar and numerous form elements.  I then have a class called MButtonBar.  This class contains a collection of MButton objects that it displays.

I have two seperate applications that will use FormControl.  These are related application.  However, in one of the applications I want it to create instances of a button called XButton, XButton being derived from MButton.

The issue is that FormControl creates the button bar and the button bar creates the buttons, all inside Common.dll, which has no knowledge of XButton.

Is there any way to have the button bar in Common.dll create an instance of XButton?  Any way using Activator.CreateInstance or a factory.  Some elegant mechanism where I pass in the class name that I want to instantiate.

The alternative solution is to derive a new FormControl and override the create button bar method.  Then derive a new button bar and create this type of button bar from my derived FormControl.  Then in the derived button bar I can override the create button method and create XButton, but this seems like a lot of work.

Comment: *The alternative solution is to derive a new FormControl and override the create button bar method.* ...this sounds correct to me.

Comment: The problem is that there are many different types of contains that create a button, other than just button bars, all of which need to create an XButton in the new application.  This would require me to derive all of these container classes, but perhaps here is no other way.

Comment: If the containers that need to create the buttons have a reference to the instance of FormControl you could add a protected internal virtual factory method on FormControl to create the buttons.  Would this approach work for you?  Then in your derived assembly you would only need to create a derived FormControl and the derived XButton.